# arithmetic mean of matrix elements and the sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have to find the arithmetic mean of the elements of the matrix and the sum of the elements of those rows of the matrix in which the element of the main diagonal is negative.

here is what I have done.

```
import numpy as np
import random
m, n = 3, 3
f_sum = 0
def row_sum(arr):
    global f_sum
    sum = 0
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            sum += arr[i][j]

            if arr[i][i] < 0:
                f_sum = sum
        sum = 0

arr = np.zeros((3, 3))

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        arr[i][j] = random.randint(-20, 20)

row_sum(arr)
mean = round(np.mean(arr), 2)
print(arr)
print('\n', "среднее арифметическое = ", mean)
print('\n',"сумму элементов = ", f_sum)
```

now the problem I am facing is that I get only the last sum when calculating for the sum of the elements of those rows in which the element of the main diagonal is negative.

the results can look like that

[image: the results can look like that]

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, but it's not working. @prhmma, we should find the sum, for each row, not adding them all.

Comment: sorry my bad, what you have to do is `f_sum +=sum`  with out plus sign you just assign sum to f_sum each time, therefore you will have last of them at the end

Comment: or maybe it's how I am printing it out?

Comment: create a new array whose length is the number of rows in `arr`. Then loop over the rows in `arr` and store the sum of the row in the new array. Also, `np.sum()` is your friend. Use it to get the sum for each row rather than the nested for loops.

Comment: Thanks, @chris, lemme try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more numpy 'esque'  approach would be something like this

```
import numpy as np

n, m = 3, 3

arr = np.random.randint(-20,20, size=(n,m))
print(arr)

diag  = np.diagonal(arr)
w     = diag < 0
f_sum = np.sum(arr[w], axis=1)

print(f_sum)
```

- You extract the diagonal elements in `diag` using `np.diagonal`.
- You find for which rows the diagonal element is negative storing it in `w`.
- Finally you select only the rows indicated by `w` and sum them.

Comment: wow...
this one looks awesome.
but it's also printing one sum, 
if by chance there are 2 negative numbers in the main diagonal, it's printing the last sum it remembers, it's supposed to print all of them.

Comment: Oh i thought it needed the global sum, (the sum of all row where the diagonal is negative not jsut the last one).  Anyway the fix is simple, add ',axis=1' in np.sum i will also update the answer